# Open PDF-File out of a Phonegap-App which includes generated code (Adapt Learning)

Tags: html, cordova, pdf, phonegap-build, adapt

I'm using Adapt Learning to create responsive E-Learning courses. I downloaded the course code (HTML5, less, CSS, JavaScript) and wrapped it into a mobile application by using PhoneGap Build (cli 6.5.0). Now I want to open the attached PDF-Files. The code is generated and I don't want to change it cause its more efficiency for upcoming projects. I have already created my config.xml in which I tried this:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

Generated Code:

```
<button class="base resources-item-open drawer-item-open" data-href="course/en/assets/bec3d79837937eab7f5937b3beb9d66bb0b89943.PDF" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Documents. . Training Solutions. ">
    <div class="drawer-item-title">
        <div class="drawer-item-title-inner h5">Training Solutions</div>
    </div>
    <div class="drawer-item-description">
        <div class="drawer-item-description-inner"></div>
    </div>
</button>
```

I need a solution which works for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get a faster answer here: https://community.adaptlearning.org/mod/forum/view.php?id=4

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't many threads about PhoneGap. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: Dear Emjay, the community could give you some pointers there. The forum is very active, and I doubt if there are folks monitoring here.

Comment: Thanks John. I already posted my issue.
https://community.adaptlearning.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=1968